# How to know if a model is composed of a group of models?

Tags: models, 3d-meshes, 3dsmax

I've downloaded a model, and try to ungroup the model and learn how this model was made. However, the big model in the image below can not be ungrouped anymore.

I feel that this model is composed of a group of models, but I cannot ungroup this model and unlink it. Is there other methods to test if this model is a model or a group of models?

Thanks in advance.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF2SM.png]

> Full Size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF2SM.png

Comment: I don't think this is particularly on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open up the [scene explorer](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/3ds-Max-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-2569461E-C859-4D54-BAFF-C8BD078B53AC.htm,topicNumber=d30e525282) (Alt+Ctrl+O), you can see what the scene is composed of:

[image]

If there are multiple meshes, you'll be able to see them here. If it's all one mesh, it will show up as a single mesh.